# JavaScript regex to replace every nn with n*n

Tags: javascript, regex, iteration

If I do this:

```
my_string = 'nnn';
my_string = my_string.replace(/nn/g, 'n*n');
return my_string; //n*nn
```

I get this result `n*nn`, but I need to insert asterisk `*` between every occasion of `nn`. The result should be `n*n*n`.

If `my_string = 'nnnn'`, the result will be `n*nn*n`, but should be `n*n*n*n`.

Comment: replace(/n(?=n)/g, 'n*')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use look-ahead:

```js
my_string = 'nnnnnnnnnnnnn';
my_string = my_string.replace(/n(?=n)/g, 'n*');
console.log(my_string);
```

Comment: I think it is right way, because it is the single regex without any additional constructions. This way force JavaScript engine to check every character and I shouldn't afraid that the rule wouldn't be applied for some neighbour character. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this replacement 2 times like this

```
'nnnnnn'.replace(/nn/g,'n*n').replace(/nn/g,'n*n');
```

Example:

```js
my_string = 'nnnnnn';
my_string = my_string.replace(/nn/g,'n*n').replace(/nn/g,'n*n');
console.log(my_string);
```